# Tag cloud control for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

Could anyone provide me an implementation of a tag cloud control for WPF, o point me to a site that shares one?

I am developing a WPF aplication with Visual Studio 2010, and I am using .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag cloud in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735563/tag-cloud-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search for "wpf tag cloud" yielded this: http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18

It is also the same answer for this SO question: [Tag cloud in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735563/tag-cloud-in-wpf)