# Tag cloud in WPF

Tags: wpf, tag-cloud

Anyone knows how to create one? I know this question has been asked before but there was no answer and the provided link was a dead end.

EDIT

The project I found but couldn't make it work is this:
http://alanle.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/WPFTagCloud.zip

The errors I get are

1. “Assembly must be specified for XAML files that are not part of a project. Reopen this XAML file after adding it to a project, close this file and reopen it using the project it is associated with, or modify the clr-namespace to include the name of the assembly.”
2. “The type ‘local:CountToFontSizeConverter’ was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.”

If someone can run it and knows how to fix it that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Aaah, tag clouds.  So pretty.  So pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at this blog post](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18).

After looking at the code in this blog post (just close the authenticate box that pops up) it looks correct. The basic idea is to bind the font size as well as the text, and calculate the font size based on the number of occurrences.

Comment: (XIII's link is bad, thus my bad)

Comment: 2018: Link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

A simple bing search came up with this: [Building a WPF Tag Cloud](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18).

Comment: Indeed. It just took me more time to have markdown properly made up :-).

Comment: That's the link I mentioned that was a dead end. I found the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: ?? you didn't specify any link in your original question. If it doesn't work simply create a new thread and specify what's not working for you.